# Thumbnail and image management

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I always though the the image manager into wp is not really good... I need to be able to generate square or custom size when i like where i like, much like **TimThumb** that generate thum on the fly... but a little complicated...

what do you use or what is the best plugin...

Comment: What do you mean by 'on the fly'.

Comment: example [thumb id="123" sizew="300px"] and that create a version of the photo width 300px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find this faboulous article... just copy/paste it here for future reference : http://webdeveloperplus.com/wordpress/how-to-use-thumbnails-generated-by-wordpress-in-your-theme/

Answer (score 1):

I made my own, but I only included the basic parameters. Just place this code in your theme's `functions.php` file. You will need to update the path to timThumb.

```
// [timThumb id="123" w="300"]
function timThumb_func( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
        'w' => '',
        'h' => '',
        'q' => '90'
    ), $atts ) );

    $timThumbPath = 'Path/to/timThumb.php';
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id );

    if(!$image) {
        return
    } else {
        return '<img src="'.$timThumbPath.'?src='.$image[0].'&w='.$w.'&h='.$h.'&q='.$q.'" />';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'timThumb', 'timThumb_func' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this plugin:

http://austinmatzko.com/wordpress-plugins/filosofo-custom-image-sizes/